# SELECT statement to show extra columns

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, select

Table1

Code   |    Type    |    Color   |    Description   |

1      |   Fruit    |   Red      |   apple

1      |   Fruit    |   Orange   |  peach

1      |   Fruit    |   Blue     |  blueberry

1      |   Fruit    |   Green    |  sour apple

1      |   Fruit    |   Yellow   |  lemon

I'm running the code below:

```
SELECT
code,
type,
color,
description
FROM table
```

If someone sends me a CSV with additional columns is there a code that I can add that produces the string **Error** in the additional columns fields?

I won't know the additional columns name since it's up to the user to designate it--All I want to produce is the effect that if they did I'll know if there was an additional field added.

Comment: Be carefull with the column names `code` and `type`. They are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html).

Comment: SQL statements have nothing to do with CSV files. Explain what you are doing (or what you want to do).

Comment: @LorenzoGatti I'm using a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement to upload CSV files locally and spot check them for errors--After I load the file into my data I want to find if someone includes extra columns other than the ones above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL LOAD DATA command

- Ignores extra columns in the input file and possibly produces a warning if they are found
- Doesn't give names to input file columns; it assigns their values to table columns and variables, which are fixed (either implicit in the tble definition or explicit in the LOAD DATA command)

In other words, you'll always load *Code*, *Type*, *Color* and *Description* into your table, regardless of input malformations.

There is a possible workaround to find lines with one or more extra columns: load the file into an empty auxiliary table with 5 columns with a NULL default. If any line in the CSV file has 5 or more columns, the test table will contain records in which the fifth column `IS NOT NULL`; you can count them.